# How to add attribute to Soap Element correct in java

Tags: java, soap

I want to add attribute to soap element like

```
<SdcPDU xmlns="urn:sdcf:sdc:xsd:faa.2.0">
<Revision>2.0.2</Revision>
</SdcPDU>
```

java code

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(); 
...
SOAPElement sdcPDU = soapBody.addChildElement("SdcPDU");
Name sdcPDUPduName = envelope.createName("xmlns");
sdcPDU.addAttribute(sdcPDUPduName, "urn:sdcf:sdc:xsd:faa.2.0");
SOAPElement revision = sdcPDU.addChildElement("Revision");
revision.addTextNode(2.0.2);
...
...
soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

but output message looks like

```
<SdcPDU xmlns="">
   <Revision xmlns="urn:sdcf:sdc:xsd:faa.2.0">2.0.2</Revision>
</SdcPDU>
```

can anyone help me!

Comment: In your reference example, the namespace is applied to SdcPDU. This will be the default namespace applied to the child elements of SdcPDU element. i am not sure why the namespace gets appended to the child element. But in the end it is same as that of your expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following code should yield you the expected result.

```
SOAPElement sdcPDU = soapBody.addChildElement("SdcPDU","","urn:sdcf:sdc:xsd:faa.2.0");
    SOAPElement revision = sdcPDU.addChildElement("Revision");
    revision.addTextNode("2.0.2");
```

Response:

> ```
> <SOAP-ENV:Body>
>   <SdcPDU xmlns="urn:sdcf:sdc:xsd:faa.2.0">
>       <Revision>2.0.2</Revision>
>   </SdcPDU>
> </SOAP-ENV:Body>
> ```